# Leakage message from sanitizer for program that does not allocate anything

Tags: c++, allocator, placement-new, sanitizer

I have some code that does almost nothing, but it does so in a convoluted way. Most importantly, it does not allocate anything. All data is on the stack. It works just fine with many versions of gcc and clang, both on my computer as well as with Godbolds compiler explorer. It does not matter if I compile with `-std=20` or `-std=17`. This is how I compile.

```
g++  -std=c++17  -g -O0  -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer  leaking_memory.cpp
```

However, if I replace the default copy ctor of `arena_ptr` with a manual implementation, then the sanitizer will report a memory leakage.
I can reproduce this with different version of gcc and clang on my computer. I can also reproduce this with different version of gcc on Godbold but not clang.
Crucially, I am not able to reproduce this error without copying an `arena_ptr` into a lambda capture (see function `f` below). This I would like to understand. Here is my code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <functional>

struct arena {
    alignas(64) std::byte memory_[1000000] = {std::byte{}};
    std::byte *pos_ = memory_;
    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    T *new_object(Args &&...args) {
        auto *ptr = new (pos_) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        pos_ += sizeof(T) + (size_t(pos_) % 8UL);
        return ptr;
    }
};

arena * a_ptr = nullptr;

template<typename T>
struct arena_ptr {
    T *value_ptr_ = nullptr;
    explicit arena_ptr(T *value_ptr_) : value_ptr_(value_ptr_) {}
    arena_ptr() = delete;
    arena_ptr(arena_ptr const &) = default;
    //inline arena_ptr(arena_ptr const &other) : value_ptr_(other.value_ptr_) {}
    arena_ptr(arena_ptr &&) = delete;
    arena_ptr &operator=(arena_ptr const &) = delete;
    arena_ptr &operator=(arena_ptr &&) = delete;
    ~arena_ptr() = default;
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
arena_ptr<T> make_arena_ptr(Args &&...args) {
    T *ptr = a_ptr->new_object<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return arena_ptr(ptr);
}

struct TT {};

struct CC {
    using PP = std::function<bool()>;
    PP pp;
    CC(CC const &) = default;
    explicit CC(PP pp) : pp(std::move(pp)) {}
};

auto f(arena_ptr<TT> left) {
    auto f = [left]() { return true; };
    return make_arena_ptr<CC>(f);
}

auto g() {
    auto int_number = []() { return make_arena_ptr<TT>(); };
    return f(int_number());
}

int main() {
    arena a;
    a_ptr = &a;
    auto program = g();
}
```

And this is the output when I use the manual ctor definition of the `arena_ptr`:

```
=================================================================
==1==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks
Direct leak of 8 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f2af4f9c528 in operator new(unsigned long) (/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/lib64/libasan.so.8+0xdb528) (BuildId: c9b24be17e4cbd04bdb4891782c4425e47a9259a)
    #1 0x401b44 in _M_create<f(arena_ptr<TT>)::<lambda()>&> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/std_function.h:161
    #2 0x401a25 in _M_init_functor<f(arena_ptr<TT>)::<lambda()>&> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/std_function.h:215
    #3 0x401961 in function<f(arena_ptr<TT>)::<lambda()>&> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/std_function.h:449
    #4 0x40172f in new_object<CC, f(arena_ptr<TT>)::<lambda()>&> /app/example.cpp:10
    #5 0x401607 in make_arena_ptr<CC, f(arena_ptr<TT>)::<lambda()>&> /app/example.cpp:35
    #6 0x4012f1 in f(arena_ptr<TT>) /app/example.cpp:54
    #7 0x401467 in g() /app/example.cpp:59
    #8 0x4015a8 in main /app/example.cpp:65
    #9 0x7f2af491a082 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082) (BuildId: 1878e6b475720c7c51969e69ab2d276fae6d1dee)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 8 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

Comment: `std::function<bool()>;` does dynamic allocation, internally. The shown code is quite convoluted, but I suspect that it's constructing an instance of this `std::function`, but does not formally destroy it, thus leaking memory.

Comment: Yeah, I see the call to `make_arena_ptr` in the stack trace.  That's what's happening. You need to placement-destroy, in addition to doing a placement-new.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, you are totally correct. `std::function` allocates because it captures more than 16 bytes. But then sanitizer should complain regardless if the default copy ctor of `arena_ptr` is defaulted or defined by user.

Comment: I guess it depends on what the default one does, vs. the user-defined one.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, the user defined one is commented below the defaulted one. I thought it is the same.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, but I am happy with your answer. +1 for your answer.

Comment: The existence of a user-defined constructor may also trigger different behavior of copy-elision, in certain circumstances. This can be the discriminating factor here. I don't have my brain wrapped around everything that happens here, but that's the first thing that comes to mind, based on what you describe.